# Aceess 2007 List Box prompt for input if i select one item?

Tags: ms-access

I have a List Box with two options; one is the default option but if I click on OTHER, I want it to pop up an inputbox for information.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use the listbox afterupdate event. It will return what the user typed in into `usrValue`.  You will need to change the `List0` to whatever the name of your control is within your access application.

```
Private Sub List0_AfterUpdate()
    Dim usrValue As String   'what the user will by saving there value into.  
    If List0.Value = "OTHER" Then
        usrValue = InputBox("Please enter a value for me", "Need something")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I changed to and it work.change the store value field to the correct one: Private Sub List0_AfterUpdate()
    Dim usrValue As String    usrValue = InputBox("Please enter a value for me", "Need something")
List0.Value = "OTHER"

Comment: @pmoney please mark the question answered if your question was answered.